# How to use IMAP on localhost for gmail?

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I am making application that is a simple mail client. But when I try `imap_open()` for gmail account with valid password and username it says `unvalid credetinals` and I recieve mail tried to access from non secure medium in my gmail specified in the function `imap_open()` How can I make this function working in `localhost`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a IMAP library available on github